# Finding intersection multiplicities of a tangent line and a quartic

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was given the following exercise. Consider the quartic curve $f(x) = xy^3 + yz^3 + zx^3 = 0$ in $P_\mathbb{C}^2$. And let $L$ be the tangent line at $P = [0:0:1]$. I need to find the intersection points of $L$ with the curve $f=0$ and the intersection multiplicities.

My attempt:

I know that by Bezout's theorem, I have that the number of intersections counted with multiplicity would be $4 \times 1 =4$. To find the equation of the line $L$ I have calculated the gradient of the curve:
$$grad f = (y^3 + 3x^2 z, 3y^2x+z^3,3yz^2+x^3)$$

which at the point $P$ is given by $(0,1,0)$. So the equation of the tangent line is $(0,1,0) \cdot (x,y,z) = 0$ or more concisely $y=0$. To find the intersection points I plugged in $y=0$ in the equation of the quartic and obtained: $$zx^3 = 0$$, which is only satisfied by the points $P_1 = [1:0:0]$ and $P_2 = [0:0:1]$. Now I'm not quite sure if what I did is correct and how to proceed to find the intersection multiplicities (which I would guess to be 3 for $P_1$ and 1 for $P_2$).

Comment: This curve is the [Klein quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic).

Comment: Everything you've done so far is correct. What definition do you have for intersection multiplicities? By the way, your question appears cut off in middle of the final sentence.

Comment: @KReiser the definition I was given was in terms of "local rings" but I have trouble understanding what it means. I think I will post a separate question about that and listing what parts I found confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right on. From your comment, I'm guessing that your definition of intersection multiplicity of affine plane curves $C: F(x,y) = 0$ and $D: G(x,y) = 0$ at a point $P$ with corresponding maximal ideal $m$ is
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
I_P(C \cap D) = \dim_{\C} \left(\frac{\C[x,y]}{(F,G)}\right)_m \, .
\end{align*}

I'll compute the multiplicity for $P_2$ and leave $P_1$ to you. Since intersection multiplicity is a local quantity we can compute it in an affine patch. Consider the affine open where $z \neq 0$ with affine coordinates $u = x/z$ and $v = y/z$. Your computations show that $(f,y) = (y, x^3 z)$, which on this affine patch corresponds to $(v,u^3)$. The ring $\C[u,v]/(v,u^3)$ is already local, so localizing at $m = (u,v)$ doesn't change anything, and we have
$$
\frac{\C[u,v]}{(v,u^3)} \cong \frac{\C[u]}{(u^3)} \cong \C \oplus \C u \oplus \C u^2
$$
as $\C$-vector spaces, so its dimension is $3$.

Comment: Thanks, sorry my algebra is a bit rusty. Could you explain why "The ring $\mathbb{C}[u,v]/(v,u^3)$ is already local"?

Comment: @mathripper The ideals of $\mathbb{C}[u,v]/(v,u^3)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $\mathbb{C}[u,v]$ containing $(v,u^3)$ and a maximal (hence prime) ideal containing $(v,u^3)$ must contain $u$ and $v$. So $(u,v)$ is the unique maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[u,v]/(v,u^3)$.